# Share url+image+text with Twitter/Facebook/Instagram

Tags: facebook, flutter, twitter, dart, instagram

Is there any lib/package that will help in both platform iOS and Android to share image+text+url on FB, Twitter And Insta? I have been searing for 4 hours but didn't find any result. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share_me 
this package is only for android so. If you have any solution for it please guide me.

~ PS : I don't want to use Share package, I have buttons of FB, Insta and Twitter. When user will click on any one of the button then data should be share on any of the social media and I need call back of failure or success.

Comment: Share a URL that has og-tags on it for description and image.

Comment: _“and I need call back of failure or success”_ - what for? Please be aware that rewarding users for sharing in any way is explicitly forbidden at least for Facebook (and probably Instagram too.)

Comment: In my case, my app is based on sharing and earning money, SO how can I get sharing on fb is done or not ? If user will share then he/she will get money

Comment: that use case is not allowed, as 04FS mentioned already. people need to share stuff because they like it, not because they get something from it.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit** 
package social_share_plugin
https://github.com/romatroskin/social_share_plugin 
provide share function and have call back 
description page forget to mention twitter already include

[image]

full social_share_plugin example code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:social_share_plugin/social_share_plugin.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _platformVersion = 'Unknown';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    String platformVersion;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      platformVersion = await SocialSharePlugin.platformVersion;
    } on PlatformException {
      platformVersion = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _platformVersion = platformVersion;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Text('Running on: $_platformVersion\n'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Share to Instagram'),
              onPressed: () async {
                File file = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
                await SocialSharePlugin.shareToFeedInstagram("image/*", file.path);
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Share to Facebook'),
              onPressed: () async {
                File file = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
                await SocialSharePlugin.shareToFeedFacebook('test', file.path);
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Share to Facebook Link'),
              onPressed: () async {
                String url = 'https://flutter.dev/';
                final quote =
                    'Flutter is Google’s portable UI toolkit for building beautiful, natively-compiled applications for mobile, web, and desktop from a single codebase.';
                final result = await SocialSharePlugin.shareToFeedFacebookLink(
                  quote: quote,
                  url: url,
                  onSuccess: (postId) {
                    print('FACEBOOK SUCCESS $postId');
                    return;
                  },
                  onCancel: () {
                    print('FACEBOOK CANCELLED');
                    return;
                  },
                  onError: (error) {
                    print('FACEBOOK ERROR $error');
                    return;
                  },
                );

                print(result);
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Share to Twitter'),
              onPressed: () async {
                String url = 'https://flutter.dev/';
                final text =
                    'Flutter is Google’s portable UI toolkit for building beautiful, natively-compiled applications for mobile, web, and desktop from a single codebase.';
                final result = await SocialSharePlugin.shareToTwitter(
                    text: text,
                    url: url,
                    onSuccess: (_) {
                      print('TWITTER SUCCESS');
                      return;
                    },
                    onCancel: () {
                      print('TWITTER CANCELLED');
                      return;
                    });
                print(result);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share 
github https://github.com/esysberlin/esys-flutter-share 
iOS need special action, you can see IMPORTANT Note for iOS

Share text:

```
Share.text('my text title', 'This is my text to share with other applications.', 'text/plain');
```

Share file:

```
final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/image1.png');
await Share.file('esys image', 'esys.png', bytes.buffer.asUint8List(), 'image/png', text: 'My optional text.');
```

Share files:

```
final ByteData bytes1 = await rootBundle.load('assets/image1.png');
final ByteData bytes2 = await rootBundle.load('assets/image2.png');
final ByteData bytes3 = await rootBundle.load('assets/addresses.csv');

await Share.files(
    'esys images',
    {
        'esys.png': bytes1.buffer.asUint8List(),
        'bluedan.png': bytes2.buffer.asUint8List(),
        'addresses.csv': bytes3.buffer.asUint8List(),
    },
    '*/*',
    text: 'My optional text.');
```

Share file from url:

```
var request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse('https://shop.esys.eu/media/image/6f/8f/af/amlog_transport-berwachung.jpg'));
var response = await request.close();
Uint8List bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
await Share.file('ESYS AMLOG', 'amlog.jpg', bytes, 'image/jpg');
```

official demo

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your help but Sorry for missing information in question. Actually client does not want to use Share package.. I will update in question. I have fb button When I will click on FB button post will share on FB and I will get callback of failure and success.

Comment: I have edit my answer. you can use https://github.com/romatroskin/social_share_plugin , it also provide call back

Comment: @chunhunghan is there any way to share text plus image in facebook

Comment: @azhar I so similar question on stackoverflow. but I did not find related package on pub.dev.

Comment: I have similar challenge, the. shareFiles() method does not share text and image to Facebook. It works perfectly with WhatsApp but not with Facebook.

Comment: Share package doesnt work to share text+image on facebook n instagram

Answer (score 1):

Allowing users to choose their social platform within your apps UI is not really viable anymore. Better to allow the user to enable their platforms in the OS and then let the Share API or Activity view in iOS do the rest. Just provide the correctly structured URLs with tags etc. This is a great resource: https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls