# In a Flutter app, is there a way to share images & text to a Facebook group?

Tags: facebook, flutter, social-media

We currently have a Flutter based app. Today, my boss asked me is there a way to share images & text to a **Facebook group** (**or groups**)? I tested several plugins, none of them can do this.

So if you know a way to do this, please tell me how to do it or what package I should use.

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58297219/share-urlimagetext-with-twitter-facebook-instagram` hope it helps@Jack Sun

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Facebook Graph API's to post text & images to Facebook group or a Facebook page.